# Optimization of bitwise & result

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm reading a stopbit encoded data stream, and I need to be able to identify the byte that has the stopbit.

A snippet of my code:

```
    const unsigned char *b; // Pointer to the datastream

    ...

    // Test the sign bit
->  if (*b & 0x40)
    {
        // Negative number, do relevant stuff
        ...
    }

    while(true)
    {
->      if (!(*b & 0x80))
        {
            // Not the stopbit
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            // Reached the stopbit, breaking out of the loop
            ...
            b++;
            break;
        }

        b++;
    }
```

This function is running in a tight loop, and needs to work in real-time. I marked with arrows the lines that the profiler shows as "hot", which are the tests for the sign bit and the stop bit.

Any ideas how I can get these operations optimized (especially the sign bit test since it seems to take more time, even though it's outside the loop)?

EDIT:
Should have mentioned this before, the pointer b is used inside the loop, and therefore I can't iterate in the while().

Comment: How about processing more bytes at once? It should be trivial to check at least 8 bytes with 0x8080808080808080 and fallback to per-byte loop.

Comment: I think your profiler is lying to you.  Unless the code you have elided is *very* lightweight, I don't see how that bit-test can be the hot spot.  The only *possible* issue is if branch prediction is getting it wrong.  What optimization levels are you using?  How frequently does the stop bit occur?  Can you tolerate adding compiler specific hints to suggest which way the branch will go?

Comment: You could try `while (! (*b & 0x80))` - and then do the stopbit code after the loop.  What does the assembler look like?

Comment: What platform are you compiling for? What compiler are you using? Are these suitable for real-time requirements?

Comment: @VTT Stopbit encoding works on a per-byte basis and I need to do things with the bytes inside the loop

Comment: @MartinBonner The code that's missing is mostly bit shifts and bitwise ORs. It is very lightweight. I'm using full optimization favoring fast code on MSVC 141 compiler. The stop bit can happen at the range of 1 to 9 bytes

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm mostly concerned with the sign bit test (*b & 0x40), as the profiler shows it as taking more time than the other test which is inside the loop

Comment: most probably `(*b & 0x40)` is a cache miss, from what you presented it's the first load of this memory block. there's not enough info to suggest improvements. it's possible it's unavoidable

Comment: @Gruffalo That might be it. Unfortunate if this is the case

Comment: depends from which angle you look at it :) if it's the most expensive part in your implementation, and if it's unavoidable - congratulations, it's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the `while(true)` in conjunction with the (additional) testing inside the loop.
But I'm not sure if this is really the issue, because the "not the stop bit"-code will very likely take much longer than the bit test.

```
unsigned char c = 1;
while ( !((c=*p++) & 0x80)) {
    // Not the stop bit stuff
    printf ("%d\n", c);
}
// stop bit reached stuff
```

Comment: Probably should have mentioned this before, but the pointer is used inside the loop, I can't iterate it in the while(). I'll add this in the edit